# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/20/9628620/html/home.php on line 59 errno 1064

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've been trying to make a dynamic class for my mysqli queries because I'm pretty sick of typing them in all the time. I've got far enough to make it throw no errors until trying to parse the returned data on the page. The above error is throwing when I try to output my query on the page. I'm leaving my old code in there to try and show what I was doing.

home.php

```
<?php
                require('config/dbconfig.php');
                include('classes/mysqli.class.php');
                $mysqli = new DATABASE($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
                $results = $mysqli->select('id,title,category,desc,postdate,author','news',null,null,'orderByLimit','id','DESC',4);
                /*
                $query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
                    // execute statement
                    $stmt->execute();

                    // bind result variables
                    $stmt->bind_result($idn, $titlen, $categoryn, $descn, $postdaten, $authorn);

                    // fetch values
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    */
                        //echo 'id: '. $id .' title: '. $title;
                        echo "<table border='0'>";
                        foreach($results as $row)
                        {

                        $shortDescLengthn = strlen($row['desc']);
                        if ($shortDescLengthn > 106) {
                            $sDCutn = 106 - $shortDescLengthn;
                            $shortDescn = substr($row['desc'], 0, $sDCutn);
                        } else {
                            $shortDescn = $row['desc'];
                        }
                        echo "<h1>" . $row['title'] . "</h1>"; 
                        echo "<tr><td>$shortDescn...</td></tr>"; 
                        echo '<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="' 
                        . 'readMore(' . $row['id'] . ',' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row['title'])) . ',' 
                        . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row['category'])) . ',' 
                        . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row['desc'])) . ',' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row['postdate'])) . ',' 
                        . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row['author'])) . ')">Read More</a></td></tr>'; 
                        echo "<tr><td>Written by: " . $row['author'] . "</td></tr>"; 
                        echo '<tr><td><img src="images/hardcore-games-newsbar-border.png" width="468px" /></td></tr>'; 
                    }
                    echo "</table><br />";

                    /*
                    //close statement
                    $stmt->close();
                }

                //close connection
                $mysqli->close();
                */
            ?>
```

mysqli.class.php

```
<?php
class DATABASE
{
private $db_host;
private $db_user;
private $db_pass;
private $db_name;
private $connection;
private $paramaters = array();
private $results = array();
private $numrows;

public function __construct($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name)
{
    $this->host = $db_host;
    $this->user = $db_user;
    $this->pass = $db_pass;
    $this->name = $db_name;
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name) or die('There was a problem connecting to the database!');
}
public function __destruct()
{
    $mysqli->close();
}
public function select($fields, $from, $where, $whereVal, $type, $orderByVal, $ASDESC, $limitVal)
{
    if ($whereVal != null)
    {
        if (is_int($whereVal))
        {
            $bindVal = 'i';
        } elseif (is_string($whereVal)){
            $bindVal = 's';
        } else {
            return 'Invalid variable type!';
        }
    }       if (count($whereVal) > 1)
    {
        $y = array();
        foreach($whereVal as $type => $brand)
        {
            $y[$type] = $brand;
        }
    } else 
    {
        $y = $bindVal;
    }
    switch($type)
    {
        case "regular":
            $queryPre = "SELECT " . $fields;
            $querySuff = " WHERE " . $where . " =  ?";
            break;
        case "orderByLimit":
            $queryPre = "SELECT " . $fields;
            $querySuff = " ORDER BY " . $orderByVal . " " . $ASDESC . " LIMIT " . $limitVal;
            break;
    }
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($queryPre . " FROM " . $from . " " . $querySuff) or die('There was a problem preparing the Query!');

    //bind parameters for markers
    if($y&&$queryPre&&$querySuff)
    { 
        $bind_names[] = $y; 
        for ($i=0; $i<count($whereVal);$i++)  
        { 
            $bind_name = 'bind' . $i; 
            $$bind_name = $whereVal[$i]; 
            $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name; 
        } 
        $return = call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),$bind_names); 
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
    {
        $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        $x = array();
        foreach($row as $key => $val)
        {
            $x[$key] = $val;
        }
        $results[] = $x;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $results;
}
/*
 * Function Insert
 * @param into
 * @param values
 * @returns boolean
*/
public function insert($into, $values)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO " . $into . " VALUES(" . $values . ")";

    $this->last_query = $query;

    if($this->mysqli->query($query))
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

/*
 * Function Delete
 * @param from
 * @param where
 * @returns boolean
*/
public function delete($from, $where)
{
    $query = "DELETE FROM " . $from . " WHERE " . $where;

    $this->last_query = $query;

    if($this->mysqli->query($query))
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
?>
```

Again, I'm not getting any errors at least loading home.php except the error in the title of this question. If I remove the foreach then it just doesn't return anything at all, but no errors. If I forget something, please, let me know kindly. I and my son have been pretty sick and I'm really tired.

Comment: I don't see the initialization of `$results` variable used in foreach

Comment: I hit undo by accident before i copy/pasted code on here, and I guess that's what got undid. Added in on the call to mysqli->connect.

Comment: have you tried to dump the content of $results? what does `var_dump($results)` output?

Comment: Putting it here:
    $stmt->close();
    var_dump($results);
    return $results;

It's just a blank page on classes/mysqli.class.php. Taking out the foreach in home.php and dumping results right after call I get this: string(22) "Invalid variable type!"

Comment: And I fixed that adding a check to see if whereVal was null or not. It's not preparing the query now.

Comment: Also, I'm getting errno 1064.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach() does not work because either there is no matching data, or your query is malformed somehow.

In the case of the latter, build your sql statement into a var and echo it out onto the screen as a form of debug:  eg:

```
$sql = $queryPre . " FROM " . $from . " " . $querySuff;

echo $sql;
```

Paste that into your db and see, does it look well formed, does it create errors, is there matching data? (a positive result?) look closely at the error messages.

Comment: Getting this: string(81) "SELECT id,title,category,desc,postdate,author FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4". It is stopping at preparing the query though if I remove that debug. Thats the exact query I have commented out in home.php above that worked, minus the fields being named instead of just *.

Comment: Sorry to double post, but I put single quotes around the queryPre, from, and querySuff as well as the orderby value and limit value hoping it would help, but still nothing. I'm stumped.

Comment: It was quotes and me forgetting to take out utilizing a new mysqli class in the config. Thanks! Took me forever to catch lol.